# Pointed colorbar in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, colorbar

I am trying to produce a figure in Matlab suitable for publication, and I need some help with the colorbar.

My data ranges from -20 to 30, but I want the colorbar to focus on -15 to 15, with arrows at each end to represent values outside that range.

I have tried using the class "pointyColorbar" (http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/answers/48773) but it doesn't produce the required output. Ideally, I would like the colorbar to look like the one below, but using my custom colormap.

Can anyone help me out with this? Sorry if I haven't asked the question right - I am new to this!

[image]

As requested, below is what I currently have for my colorbar (cmap is my custom color map):

```
cmap=precipanomcolourmap(7,7)
colormap(cmap)
caxis([-20 30])
cb=colorbar('location','southoutside');
set(get(cb,'title'),'string','Average annual precipitation anomaly (%)','FontWeight','bold');
set(cb,'XTick',[-17.5 -15 -12.5 -10 -7.5 -5 -2.5 0 2.5 5 7.5 10 12.5 15 17.5]);
xlim(cb,[-17.5 17.5]);
```

This gets me a rectangular colorbar below my figure ranging from -17.5 to 17.5. The values outside of this are marked using the same colour as the +/- 15-17.5 range.

When I tried the pointyColorbar class, I replaced the `cb=colorbar('location','southoutside');` line with `cb=pointyColorbar(15,-15,'location','southoutside')`. It may well be that I need to play around with how to use the pointyColorbar class, but I don't understand the code well enough to know how to get it to look how I want it.

Comment: Could you show us what you have done so far in MATLAB?

Comment: I have added some code above :)

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using? I saw that the functions `isrow` and `iscolumn` in the pointyColorbar are only available from MATLAB R2011a. Also, the `poly2mask` function is available in the Image Processing Toolbox, so the class won't work if you don't have that toolbox.

Comment: I am using MATLAB R2013a, and I also have the Image Processing Toolbox. My MATLAB license is through my university, so I have quite a lot of the toolboxes.
When I did use the pointyColorbar class, it basically had the colorbar in a rectangular box with some arrows within it, but it didn't look right. Not sure if I can post the image of it though.

Comment: The class seem to works for loading images, I don't know if it will work with `contour` function.

Comment: I am actually using the pcolor function. The image above was just an example of how I want the colorbar to look. When I get a chance, I am going to have another play around with the pointyColorbar class to see if I can get it to work.
Is there any other way I can get a colorbar like the one above?

Answer (score 0):

About the poining issue, I think your answer is as the bottom of this page:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/48773

and about the colorbar limits, I think you are looking for something like:

set(gca, 'CLim', [cLow, cHigh]);

before dislaying the colorbar.

('cLow' and 'cHigh' are the limits you want for the colorbar).

Take a look at this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/163344

Comment: The code I wrote shouldn't produce that example. I just want the colourbar to look like that - the rest of the figure is irrelevant (the positioning of the colourbar is already sorted). The limits were working fine, it was literally just the pointy bit I was trying to do.

Comment: Ok, sorry couldn' help you with that. I'll write you back if I find out.

Comment: I've edited my answer. I believe know you have what you want.

Comment: If you re-read my original question, you will see that I have already tried using pointyColorbar which I couldn't get to work how I wanted to.